# react native: Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method RCTEventEmitter.receiveTouches

Tags: react-native

I am writing native modules for react native, while runing app in react native, I am getting the following error in react native:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:151 Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method RCTEventEmitter.receiveTouches(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
reactConsoleErrorHandler    @   ExceptionsManager.js:151
registerError   @   LogBox.js:187
console.error   @   LogBox.js:67
overrideMethod  @   backend.js:2082
reportException @   ExceptionsManager.js:95
handleException @   ExceptionsManager.js:141
handleError @   setUpErrorHandling.js:24
reportFatalError    @   error-guard.js:49
__guard @   MessageQueue.js:369
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  @   MessageQueue.js:112
(anonymous) @   debuggerWorker.js:69
```

not able to figure out source of error.